# OWA: Changing Email password through a script

Tags: bash, outlook-web-app

Is there a way to change my outlook web app client password with the help of a bash script? If yes, then please suggest how. My company has implemented a policy to change my password every 21st day. I'm tired of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab yourself a Firefox web browser and install the extension "LiveHTTPHeaders". It can log all the headers that are sent between your web browser and your companies server. Then you fire up wget with the `--save-cookies cookie_file` and try to repeat the communication with your server. From the first call on you use `--load_cookies cookie_file` so the server knows who you are. You can find out more about wget [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html).

In case you can use perl/ruby/python I would recommend [mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) which is a parser that helps you find all links in a webpage for example.

Comment: @Ankit Garg: if you want further help you need to ask a question. Tell what you tried to do and where you have problems.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I didn't mean to share the URL. It was accidently shared. Sorry to bother you all.